# Por que o Slim Framework funciona no meu computador mas não funciona no servidor na internet?

Tags: php, slimframework

index.php

```
<?php require_once"header.php"; ?>

<?php
    use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
    use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

    require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

    $app = AppFactory::create();
    $app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

    $app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) 
    {
        require_once("nav/home.php");
        return $response;
    });
    $app->get('/sobre', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) 
    {
        require_once("nav/sobre.php");
        return $response;
    });  
    $app->run();
?>

<?php require_once"footer.php";?>
```

Quando eu acesso a página home ('/') funciona, mas quando eu clico em "/sobre" o servidor não encontra a página, a rota não ta funcionando.

Comment: você ativou o certificado ssl no seu serviço de hospedagem ? e qual a versão do slim você esta utilizando ?

Comment: To usando o Slim 4.0. Tem que ativar o ssl? Vou pesquisar sobre isso aí.

Comment: no meu caso, assim que eu ativei o ssl as minhas rotas pararam de funcionar. Tive que alterar o arquivo .htaccess. aqui você pode encontrar como configurar o web server: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/web-servers.html

Comment: Mas onde eu tenho que digitar esse comando? Eu nem sei que tipo de servidor o 000webhost usa.

Comment: você precisa editar o arquivo .htaccess que esta no mesmo diretório que idenx.php, deixando dessa forma: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

Comment: Então eu vou criar esse arquivo pois aqui não tem nada.

Comment: provavelmente esse arquivo esta oculto, você terá que habilitar a opção para exibir arquivos ocultos. No gerenciador de arquivos do cpanel há uma opção de configuração onde você pode habilitar essa opção. https://cliente.ddrhost.com.br/knowledgebase/331/Como-exibir-arquivos-ocultos-htaccess-pelo-Gerenciador-de-Arquivos-no-cPanel.html

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99251/discussion-between-david-cesar-and-gabriel-jose-de-oliveira).